# Study error bad session section - 00 -00-09 -00 and i cant find the solution

Tags: tradingview-api

```
//@version=5
indicator('Sesiones de Trading', overlay=true)

// Definir horarios de las sesiones
asia_start = input('00:00-09:00', 'Sesión de Asia')
london_start = input('08:00-17:00', 'Sesión de Londres')
ny_start = input('14:00-23:00', 'Sesión de Nueva York')

// Determinar el inicio y final de cada sesión
asia_session = time('60', asia_start)
london_session = time('60', london_start)
ny_session = time('60', ny_start)

// Colorear las sesiones
bgcolor(asia_session ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title='Sesión de Asia')
bgcolor(london_session ? color.new(color.blue, 90) : na, title='Sesión de Londres')
bgcolor(ny_session ? color.new(color.red, 90) : na, title='Sesión de Nueva York')
```

Somebody has an idea about the error? The idea is that, according to the trading sessions in asia, new york and london, a different color box will be marked to cover those sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your input to :

```
asia_start = input.session("0000-0900", 'Sesión de Asia')
london_start = input.session("0800-1700", 'Sesión de Londres')
ny_start = input.session("1400-2300", 'Sesión de Nueva York')
```